# Why is my testLogin failing in Laravel Dusk even though I'm using the example code from the docs?

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I've just started doing browser testing with Dusk, but I can't get the default login test to work. What am I doing wrong?:

I am basically using the example code from the docs, so find it strange that it's not working.

Here's my test in its class:

```
class ExampleTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create([
            'email' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
        ]);

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('users',['email' => $user->email]);

        $this->assertTrue(Hash::check('secret', $user->password));

        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($user) {
            $browser->visit('/login')
                    ->type('email', $user->email)
                    ->type('password', 'secret')
                    ->press('Login')
                    ->assertPathIs('/home');
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my User factory:

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->safeEmail,
        'password' => bcrypt('secret'),
    ];
});
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Actual path [/login] does not equal expected path [/home].
Failed asserting that '/login' matches PCRE pattern "/^\/home$/u".
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: does your login form redirect to /home?

Comment: Yes. I've discovered something that may be relevant. My phpunit.xml is set with `<server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>`, which I think is where the factory generation is happening. But the browser test is accessing my mysql database. How do I get the browser test to use the same `:memory:` db, or can I not?

Comment: You can't use a `:memory:` database for Dusk tests. The test and your application run in separate processes and they have no way of accessing the same in-memory database.

Comment: Thanks. I discovered this since I wrote the question. I have set up a sqlite connection in database.php and and running it from that, but dusk is using the `APP_URL` value from `.env` rather than `.env.dusk.local`. I have also had to set my phpunit tests to run on sqlite instead of `:memory:`, which isn't what I want. How to get a) phpunit to run on :memory:? b) things to run on sqlite when doing dusk tests? and c) package this needly and have the right env values loaded?

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue and somehow figured it out by changing the `->assertPathIs('/')` to be the same as `$browser->visit('/')`. It worked and that's all I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the same error was caused by the weird behavior of Dusk when using Laravel's database trait `use DatabaseTransactions;`. When this line is erased it's ok again. To reach the desired effect of the trait (do this only on the testing database, not production!), I added rather:

```
public function setUp(): void
{    
    parent::setUp();
    $this->artisan('migrate:fresh');
    $this->artisan('db:seed');
}
```